# scroll function inside a loop not working because of undefined property

Tags: javascript

I want to change the style of items while scrolling.
My code is working if I target the ID, but I have to target many items.
So I changed it for class name and add a "for" loop to get through every items.
It ended with the error "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined".
Can someone explain me where I am wrong ?

```js
var gear = document.getElementsByClassName("rotate-block");
for (var i = 0; i < gear.length; i++) {
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    gear[i].style.transform = "rotate("+window.pageYOffset/2+"deg)";
});
  };
```

Comment: Is your question answered? If yes, please mark the correct answer. If not, please comment accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is using a closure-based access to `i` inside the scroll listeners.

Because you defined your index using `var` rather than `let`, all these closures reference the same `i`, which is evaluated when the listener is *executed*, not when it is *defined*.

After your last iteration of the for-loop, `i` is equal to `gear.length`, which means any of the listeners is trying to access `gear[gear.length]`. The highest index available on any array is `length - 1` though.

To fix your issue, simply switch from

```
for (var i = 0; i < gear.length; i++)
```

to

```
for (let i = 0; i < gear.length; i++)
```

So this is the basis of the error you are describing...

## ...but

Why are you adding more than one scroll listener in the first place?

You probably instead want to iterate over `gear` *inside* the listener, at which point using `var` is perfectly fine since it's no longer accessed as a closure.

```js
var gear = document.getElementsByClassName("rotate-block");
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < gear.length; i++) {
        gear[i].style.transform = "rotate("+window.pageYOffset/2+"deg)";
    }
});
```

For the future, I highly recommend to switch to using `for...of` to iterate over iterables:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    for (const gear of document.getElementsByClassName("rotate-block")) {
        gear.style.transform = "rotate("+window.pageYOffset/2+"deg)";
    }
});
```

Comment: Apparently, the first part would not fix the problem. The "...but" part will ;)